# How to add limited multiple input fields while uploading pictures

Tags: javascript

I found this script online to add multiple file input fields, but I only want maximum six fields when clicking the "add" button.

However, this script allows the user to add unlimited fields. How can I limit the number of input fields to six and give default message like:

> You are only allowed to upload six pictures.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.add_field').click(function(){
     var input = $('#input_clone');
     var clone = input.clone(true);
    clone.removeAttr ('id');
    clone.val('');
    clone.appendTo('.input_holder'); 
    });
 });
  </script>
```

And HTML:

```
    <span class="add_field">+</span>
    <span class="remove_field">-</span>
  <div class="input_holder">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone"  />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of file inputs and if less than six, allow another to be added. Try:

```
 $('.add_field').click(function () {
     if ($('input[type=file]').length < 6) {
         var input = $('#input_clone');
         var clone = input.clone(true);
         clone.removeAttr('id');
         clone.val('');
         clone.appendTo('.input_holder');
     } else { alert('Only six allowed.') }
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pcc4N/2)**

Comment: Maybe time to allow other be 'faster' :D

Comment: omd pretty quick within 5 min lol u r life saver thanx it works absolutely fine

Comment: Yeah said thanks and didn't check answer as best. It's like: Thanks... I'm kidding.

Answer (score 0):

For example by using `var counter`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var counter = 0;
   $('.add_field').click(function(){
       if(counter <= 6)
           var input = $('#input_clone');
           var clone = input.clone(true);
           clone.removeAttr ('id');
           clone.val('');
           clone.appendTo('.input_holder'); 
           counter++;
      }else{
          alert('no more uploads!')      
      }
    });
 });
```